# Fill a drawed circle with the midpoint algorithm in c-> infinite-loop?

Tags: c, algorithm, infinite-loop, geometry

I am trying to draw a filled circle with the midpoint algorithm. I already managed to draw an unfilled circle with y0 = 320; x0 = 240; radius = 180 -with the following code (reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm):

```
int x0, int y0, int radius;

x0 = 320;     //assign values
y0 = 240;
radius = 180;

int x = radius-1;
int y = 0;
int dx = 1;
int dy = 1;
int err = dx - (radius << 1);

while (x >= y)
{
    putpixel(x0 + x, y0 + y);
    putpixel(x0 + y, y0 + x);
    putpixel(x0 - y, y0 + x);
    putpixel(x0 - x, y0 + y);
    putpixel(x0 - x, y0 - y);
    putpixel(x0 - y, y0 - x);
    putpixel(x0 + y, y0 - x);
    putpixel(x0 + x, y0 - y);

    if (err <= 0)
    {
        y++;
        err += dy;
        dy += 2;
    }
    if (err > 0)
    {
        x--;
        dx += 2;
        err += dx - (radius << 1);
    }
}
```

This delivers the following output (saved in a bitmap):
[image]

Now I want, that this unfilled yellow circle will be filled, so it looks like this:

[image]

I thought I can accommplish this with setting the radius everytime to radius-- so it draws the same circle with a -1 radius - and that until radius=0. So basically it draws everytime a new circle filled up with the old circle until there is now circle to draw anymore (radius=0). My code for this is:

int x0, int y0, int radius;

```
x0 = 320;     //assign values
y0 = 240;
radius = 180;

int x = radius-1;
int y = 0;
int dx = 1;
int dy = 1;
int err = dx - (radius << 1);

while(radius!=0) {
    while (x >= y)
    {
        putpixel(x0 + x, y0 + y);
        putpixel(x0 + y, y0 + x);
        putpixel(x0 - y, y0 + x);
        putpixel(x0 - x, y0 + y);
        putpixel(x0 - x, y0 - y);
        putpixel(x0 - y, y0 - x);
        putpixel(x0 + y, y0 - x);
        putpixel(x0 + x, y0 - y);

        if (err <= 0)
        {
            y++;
            err += dy;
            dy += 2;
        }
        if (err > 0)
        {
            x--;
            dx += 2;
            err += dx - (radius << 1);
        }
    }

    x0 = x0 - 1;     //getting the next circle until radius = 0
    y0 = y0 -1;
    radius = radius - 1;

    x = radius-1;
    y = 0;
    dx = 1;
    dy = 1;
    err = dx - (radius << 1);

}
```

This should be the code to my idea how I could fill up, but all i get is an infinite-loop.. Has anyone an idea why? Or has anyone another way to fill up the circle using the midpoint algorithm?

Greetings

Comment: first thing in that case: put a lot of  printfs to print values of varying indices like x, y, err in all the loops and observe where you're stuck. Also use a small circle to avoid a lot of output.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks for that advice - i will try that and lower the radius to 5. But is my idea, how I can fill up the rest, right?

Comment: oh you could also use a flood fill algorithm. I'm describing one (implemented in python) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40963288/fatal-python-error-cannot-recover-from-stack-overflow-during-flood-fill/40963737?s=2|26.2027#40963737

Comment: this would work? where can I find your algorithm? this would be awesome. 
edit: just saw you edited it - thanks :) edit2: @Jean-FrançoisFabre could you maybe give me an exaple, how I implement your fill-up-algorithm in my c-programm?

Comment: if you can convert my python code to C, you'll get a generic flood fill code, that can fill any closed form, not only a circle.

Comment: You should try debugging!

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [fast algorithm for drawing filled circles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1201200/563940).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure doing it your way won't generate a very nice circle; rounding errors and such might very well end up giving you "holes" in the circle, i.e. un-filled pixels.

A much better approach is to realize that the circle can be viewed as a bunch of horizontal lines of varying lengths. Thus, all you need to do is to iterate the `y` component from `-r` to `r`, and for each such `y` compute the corresponding `x` using your existing code. Then draw a horizontal line from `(-x, y)` to `(x, y)`.

Comment: +1 for that idea:  I already thought that - so you mean i should fill the circle up line by line? This means I should get first the starting coordinate and then the ending coordinate from a line am I right?

Comment: Yes, I mean you should draw the circle as a bunch of horizontal lines. No need to draw the actual circle (outline, un-filled) first, just draw the lines and that will be enough. You only need to compute *one* horizontal coordinate per vertical coordinate, since the circle is symmetrical as I said.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [fast algorithm for drawing filled circles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1201200/563940).